# Subproject of flat included multiproject not found in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm stuck with a transitive dependency injection in gradle. I have the following structure :

```
A/
  build.gradle.kts
  settings.gradle.kts
B/
  build.gradle.kts
  settings.gradle.kts
  C/
    build.gradle.kts
```

- A depends on project B.
- A flat include B
- B include C
- A and B are in different repositories, so no common root for them.

When I build A, I get the following error :

```
* Where:
Build file '/.../B/build.gradle.kts' line: 7
* What went wrong:
Project with path 'C' could not be found in project ':B'.
```

What should I put in `A/settings.gradle.kts` to make it work ?

---

Here is all files to reproduce my problem:

**A/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins { `java-library` }
dependencies { api(project("B")) }
```

**A/settings.gradle.kts**

```
rootProject.name = "A"
includeFlat("B")
```

**B/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins { `java-library` }
dependencies { api(project("C")) }
```

**B/settings.gradle.kts**

```
rootProject.name = "C"
include("C")
```

**B/C/build.gradle.kts**

```
plugins { `java-library` }
dependencies { }
```

Here is the output of listing projects in B

```
B/# gradle -q projects
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'B'
\--- Project ':C'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like :

A/settings.gradle.kts

```
rootProject.name = "A"
include("B", "B:C")
project(":B").projectDir = File(settingsDir, "../B")
project(":B:C").projectDir = File(settingsDir, "../B/C")
```

which results in

[gradle -q projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI9OB.png)